# Changing your web.config from your ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string

I need to change the database connection string in the web.config file but havent got a clue how to go about this. Does anyone have any experience with that?

**UPDATE**
Sorry, not very clear above, I want to be able to change a connection string from the web application after it has been deployed

Comment: Are you aware that modifying the web.config will reset your web site? You shouldn't do that.

Comment: I was not aware of that, thank you. In this case it would be okay to reset the website though as the database connection would be changing too.

Comment: I would add a comment to whatever tag(s) you change from code in the web.config to remind the viewer that this value may change. Someone taking over this code in the future who is unaware that values can change from code could become confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Configuration myConfiguration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
//appSettings configuration
myConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings["xxx"].Value = "yyy";
//database connections configuration
myConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["xxxconnection"].ConnectionString = "yyy";
myConfiguration.Save();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.connectionstrings.aspx

**Edit:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringssection.aspx

Also, as pointed out by the others, you need to set the correct permissions but sometimes using shared hosting (from experience) they ask you for the username and password of your account and once you enter that, your web.config is changed. So try it and if it doesn't work and you don't have access to set the permissions then I'm afraid you have to look into something else.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks - one change I had to make to the code above is on line 3: `myConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["xxxconnection"].ConnectionString = "yyy";`

Comment: It did, just waiting until im allowed to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WebConfigurationManager` class as shown [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Modify-Web.Config-Run-Time.aspx).

As it is very sensitive information, proper permissions need to be set as explained on [this site](http://odetocode.com/Articles/418.aspx) (link proposed by David Stratton).

Comment: Good answer.  There's a bit more, though.. Permissions need to be set properly.  This article covers that as well: http://odetocode.com/Articles/418.aspx

Comment: @David Stratton: You are right, permissions should be properly set. I will update my answer taking this into account, thank you.