# Add or Edit in webconfig file

Tags: c#, web-config

I want to add or update webconfig file in C#. How can i do this?

Comment: you want to be able to update the web.config via c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing your web.config from your ASP.NET application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915845/changing-your-web-config-from-your-asp-net-application)

Comment: With great difficulty. If your web app manages to save the file, it will restart the web application, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Your question is incredibly vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class. It will give you a [`Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) object which you can edit and call `Save` on.

Comment: And killing the web app in the process.

Comment: @leppie, sure, but that does not seem to concern the OP.

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann - can the restart be avoided or is there a way where we can do a hot deployment? plz help